# Jquery Mobile forms don't submit if input fields are inside a list view

Tags: jquery, forms, listview, mobile

I have a basic login form in my Jquery Mobile application, and since I like how the listviews look, especially with the data-inset=true, I decided to put my fields and submit button in an `<li>` tag.  However when I do this my form will not submit.  If I remove the listview code (the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags) it does work.

Here's my code with the listview:

```
<form action="index.php" name="frmLogin" method="post">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" tabindex="0">Member login</li>
            <li><input type="text" name="login-email" id="login-email" value="Email" /></li>
            <li><input type="password" name="login-password" id="login-password" value="Password" /></li>
            <li><button type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">LOG ON</button></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

So what happens is that the form does not react at all, with the above code.  It doesn't even show the standard "Loading" overlay that usually appears when you submit a form.

Any ideas?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing.  However I have noticed this only happens if you click EXACTLY on the text of the button (i.e. LOG ON)  BUT if you click an area of the button where there is no text then it submits.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used jQuery Mobile, but you could clone the form (stripping out the ul & li) when `#login-submit` is clicked and submit that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you *need* to use an `<ul>`?  You can get a similar layout by wrapping your inputs in `<div data-role="fieldcontain">`.

Take a look at [the layout and markup here, for example](http://winscrabble.com/?useiphoneview=true)

Comment: Cool example.  Yeap I was aware of the fieldcontain role but you don't get the same look as the listviews which is what I'm after.  I will have a look at the css behind the listviews and see if I can apply the same styles to a custom made element.  Otherwise fieldcontain it is!

Answer (score 0):

I've used the `data-ajax="false"` attribute, works fine for me. My input fields are in a list item aswell.

(try adding Jquery-Mobile to your post's tags to get more response :) )